# How to select a data from a table without particular value in a row in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am new MsSQL. I am doing a query as follows

I have a table called Table1 as

```
   sno    name
     1     raj
     2     sam
     3     jim
     4     Julia
```

I wanted the select the `select name FROM Table1  except value= jim`

```
    output Display as below

            name
             raj
             sam
             Julia
```

So how can I acheive it.

Comment: `where name <> 'jim'`

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name FROM Table1 WHERE name<>'jim'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:-

```
SELECT name FROM Table1 WHERE name <> 'jim'
```

you can also use NOT IN clause:-

```
SELECT name FROM Table1 WHERE name NOT IN ('jim', '<otherNameIfany>')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<>` operator can be interpreted as 'different' (the opposite for `=`), so you can include it inside a `where` clause to avoid including specific values as a result of a query execution. In your case:

```
SELECT name 
FROM Table1 
WHERE value <> 'jim';
```